# Помогите пожалуйста с GULP

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, sass, scss

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var watch = require("gulp-watch");


var sass_files = '../styles/sass/**.scss';

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(sass_files)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    // .pipe(sass({outputStyle: "compressed"}).on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../styles/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(sass_files, ['default']);
});

gulp.task('default' ['sass']);
```

делаю команду gulp и выдает ошибку

[19:08:25] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/gulpfile.js

[19:08:25] Task never defined: default

[19:08:25] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks

выполняю команду

gulp gulp --tasks

[19:09:03] Tasks for ~/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/gulpfile.js

[19:09:03] ├── sass

[19:09:03] └── watch

```js
21:34:21] Starting 'default'...
[21:34:21] Starting 'sass'...
[21:34:25] 'sass' errored after 4.25 s
[21:34:25] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Glob._process (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/glob/glob.js:299:3)
    at new Glob (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/glob/glob.js:170:10)
    at new GlobStream (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/glob-stream/readable.js:65:17)
    at streamFromPositive (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:80:12)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at globStream (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:67:27)
    at Gulp.src (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js:24:5)
    at sass (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/gulpfile.js:10:15)
    at sass (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/gulpfile.js:12:9)
    at sass (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/gulpfile.js:12:9)
[21:34:25] 'default' errored after 4.25 s
```

НОВАЯ ОШИБКА

Comment: Запятую тут забыли: `gulp.task('default' ['sass']);`

Comment: assert.js:350
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/timur/Desktop/bootstrap/gulp/gulpfile.js:21:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)

Comment: Спасибо большое))а то 10 часов сижу уже залипаю , но сейчас новая ошибка

Comment: gulp небось 4 версии? Он отличается от 3. Надо `gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['sass']));` (или `parallel` вместо `series`).

Comment: Да 4 версия геморой ) можете ватсап или вк написать ? опять ошибка новая

Comment: Ниже основного вопроса написал новую ошибку

Comment: Тут уже не знаю, почему оно зацикливается. Единственная мысль, может там какие-то линки циклические по указанному пути?